# Apply -webkit-filter:blur to fullscreen background in HTML tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
```

to my fullscreen background which is defined in my HTML tag. I would prefer to keep the background defined in this tag. I've read other posts that require the background to be defined in the body tag, but I'd ideally rather not overly restructure.

```
html {
    background: url(../img/footballbg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Any ideas on how to apply to the background, and not the children tags (body, etc)?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but I would expect bluring `html` would blur everything on the page, same with body. I recently was playing with bluring backgrounds and the best way I found was to have a fixed div with the background and apply to that. the blur filter is pretty weak right now... very limited and very resource intensive. Ideal solutions  like what you are trying to achieve are hard to come by with filters.

Comment: Fair enough - I'll take a look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole page is getting drawn and then the  is getting blurred, with all it's children. There's no way around it if you think about it.

For example, if you rotated your html, you'd expect anything in it to be rotated, right? at least then you could rotate it back, but you can't 'un-blur'...

Comment: Very true - I've never thought of it this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As said by [@climbinghobo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819076/apply-webkit-filterblur-to-fullscreen-background-in-html-tag/23819169#23819169), you can't directly apply it to `html` tag, but you can use the pseudo class `::before` to achieve it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        html {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        html::before {
            content: " ";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: url(http://placehold.it/600x400) top left repeat scroll;
            z-index: -1;
            -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
            -moz-filter: blur(5px);
            -o-filter: blur(5px);
            -ms-filter: blur(5px);
            filter: blur(5px);
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        Heyyy, this text has not been blurred!
    </body>
</html>
```

You can check it working [in this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ed96R/).

Also, take in mind that **the blur effect does not work under firefox yet** (at least does not under version < 30.0*). To get it working you'll need to use [svg filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content):

```
html::before {
  /* ... */
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
  filter: url(filters.svg#blur);
}
```

And the `filters.svg` (in this case placed under the same folder as the css file) file should contain:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

***Update:** on latest firefox versions it's working now :) (I'm currently using version 37.0a2)

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer this question, you would need either an element that is absolutely positioned with a negative z-index or a similarly styled pseudo element. That way, you are styling only the background and not the content.